# Extract positional path argument from list of arguments to "ls" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line-arguments

I am trying to parse a list of command-line arguments (contained in the special `"$@"` Bash variable) that shall be passed on to the Linux `ls` binary.

The arguments may optionally contain keyword arguments like `-h` or `--color` or `--hide 'pattern'` and they may optionally contain a directory or file path (absolute `/home`, relative `./bin` or implicitly relative `Documents`) at any position.

Is there a way to extract only the positional path argument from the list, if any is contained?

If it is not reasonably possible to rule out all edge cases, can we at least achieve the goal and extract the path argument whenever it is given as last argument on the line?

In case it helps for context, I am going to process the path argument further with `awk` in the next step to modify the output of `ls -alF` by appending further information to each line (in relation to ["show git branch in `ls -l`" on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/950075/367990)). Here I have the problem that if I run e.g. `ls -alF /home`, I have entries about `./` and `../` in the output, which `awk` will then process as relative paths to the current working directory and not to the specified `/home`.

---

The actual script (Bash function) can be found in the linked answer above on Ask Ubuntu. Here is a minimal version that skips calling the external `git` command and parsing its output:

```
lg (){ 
    ls -alF "$@" | 
    awk '{
        # Split into columns 1-8 and 9+ (file name):
        match($0, /^(\S+\s+){8}(.+)$/, f);
        # do something with the file name using an external command
        # result is stored in b, e.g. "(master)" or an empty string
        b=f[2];
        print $0, b
    }'
; }
```

Example output (of the original function that includes the external call):

```
$ lg
total 48 
drwxrwxr-x 12 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:48 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 74 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 15:30 ../ 
drwxrwxr-x  6 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:43 git1/ (master)
drwxrwxr-x  7 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:42 git2/ (develop)
drwxrwxr-x  4 bytecommander bytecommander 4096 Aug 26 14:45 no-git/ 
-rw-rw-r--  1 bytecommander bytecommander    0 Aug 26 14:42 regular-file
```

Now if my current working directory is e.g. `git1` from above (which is a repository) and I run it like `lg /home`, the `./` entry in the output of `ls` will correctly correspond to `/home`, but the repository information I add is incorrectly the one of the current working directory, i.e. `git1`. Same for the parent directory entry `../`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Working with the output of `ls` is a bad idea to start with.

Comment: @chepner I think my final goals are pretty well described in the last paragraph. What I want to achieve is to take the output of `ls -alF` as it is and extend it by appending some git meta information to all directories listed in the output. I have a working solution for that (see link), which just currently has the problem that the `.`/`..` entries are treated relative to the working directory and not to the optionally specified location argument. And yes, I know that parsing `ls` is not the best thing to do, but the alternative is to rewrite `ls`, which I want to do even less.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to write a script that's called like `myscript -alF /home` and internally calls `ls "$@"` and you want to then also inside the script call `awk '...' /home`? If so that awk call would just be `awk '...' "${!#}"` in bash - is that what you want? If not then clarify your question with a concrete example script plus sample input expected output, i.e.a [mcve].

Comment: @EdMorton I copied the stuff from my linked Ask Ubuntu answer that contained the code. Does that meet your requirements, or do you need anything else for clarification?

Comment: When posting a question you should show a [mcve] - note the word "Minimal". What you should NOT do is throw up whatever script you happen to be working on when you realize you have a question about some part of that script - create a **Minimal** script that demonstrates **this** question so those of us reading it don't have to waste time trying to figure out what a bunch of irrelevant code does. Your awk script is going to spin off into an infinite loop first time it has trouble reading the git output btw - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: I feel like what you're trying to ask about is something very simple but it's buried in so much extra detail I for one just can't figure out what it is you want (given how much time/effort I'm willing to put into any question) if not just how to use `${!#}`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for your time and input, I tried to minify my code example and leave the whole external command call out. Not sure if that is very helpful for the problem though. I also have read your linked article, but couldn't find a problem with my original getline command. Could you give me a clearer hint on what you think was wrong there, please?

Comment: When getline fails it returns `-1`. Your loop is written `while(c|getline g)` which only exits the loop when getline returns zero (i.e. successful end of input). So when `getline` fails you will continue to loop and continue to fail forever. As it shows in that article the correct way to write a getline loop would be `while((c | getline g) > 0)`.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh, now I see. Thank your for that hint.

Comment: Best I can tell from your question the answer is "use `${!#}`" - if that's not it, I just can't figure out what the question is, sorry.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, that doesn't take all possible corner cases of how you can invoke ls into account, but probably it will be my best bet for a quick and simple solution. Thanks again, I'll see if I can get it working in the next days or maybe if I have to completely abandon awk and use something more flexible like Python.

Comment: Best I can tell awk has nothing to do with your question and your question is "how do I do X in a shell script" with "X" being something to do with separating positional parameters to pass just some of them to a tool (in this case awk but could be anything) so replacing awk with python or anything else won't solve your shell problem. I'd recommend coming up with a new question that JUST focuses on whatever it is you're trying to do with these positional parameters and shows a [mcve] that includes a scenario where using `${!#}` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with perl then I suggest to use the Getopt::Long package to parse the arguments. Here's a sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Getopt::Long;

my @args = @ARGV;

GetOptions(
  'a'            => \$opt{'a'},
  'all'          => \$opt{'all'},
  'A'            => \$opt{'A'},
  'almost-all'   => \$opt{'almost-all'},
  'author'       => \$opt{'author'},
  'b'            => \$opt{'b'},
  'escape'       => \$opt{'escape'},
  'block-size=s' => \$opt{'block-size'},
  # ...
  'version'      => \$opt{'version'}
)
or die "Invalid options: @args\n";

my @fileargs = @ARGV;
print "ls args: @args\n";
print "file args: @fileargs\n";
```

For example `perl script.pl -a --author file1 file2` will print `ls args: -a --author file1 file2` `file args: file1 file2`. You may add further code to process the file arguments.

As for the relative path name problem: I suggest to run `find -maxdepth 1 fileordir` instead of `ls fileordir` to get absolute paths.

Comment: Can I get only the positional path argument and simply ignore anything else, without configuring all possible parameters somewhere first?

Comment: Well you could throw everything away that's starting with `-` since ls knows only arguments in the form `-(\w|-\w+(=\w+)?)`, but wouldn't that be a bit of a hack?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess so far is you're writing a script "myscript" which you want to call as:

```
myscript -<ls-args> <path>
```

and inside myscript do:

```
ls "$@"
awk 'stuff' "${!#}"
```

If that's not what you're looking for then edit your question to clarify.

Comment: And what does `"${!#}"` do here?

Comment: `$#` is the number of args passed to `myscript` so `${!#}` is the value of the last arg passed to `myscript`.